# Putty X11 forwarding, something not working right

Tags: ssh, putty, x11-forwarding

I have PuTTY installed and I can successfully log in to the remote host. I also have Xming installed on the same host running PuTTY. The remote host is running Ubuntu 12.04, and by default, `localhost` is set to `127.0.1.1` in the `/etc/hosts` file. When I log in, the `DISPLAY` variable is correctly set to `localhost:10.0`, but for some reason, X applications are unable to open the display:

```
[user@host ~]$ xeyes
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

However, if I set the `DISPLAY` variable to `127.0.0.1:10.0`, then X11 is successfully forwarded to Xming. If I change `localhost` on the Ubuntu box to resolve to `127.0.0.1`, it works, but a *heap* of other applications suddenly become very slow, even after a reboot. So this isn't a solution for me.

What I want to know, is what is listening on 127.0.0.1 instead of 127.0.1.1? Is it X? Or SSH? How can I force whatever it is to resolve `localhost` from `/etc/hosts` rather than assume it is `127.0.0.1`? According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), applications are allowed to make that assumption, but in my particular case it is causing me problems! Alternatively, how can I customise the `DISPLAY` variable so it is automatically set to `127.0.0.1:10.0` on login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an alias in your .bashrc  / .bash_aliases (depending on how your login resource files are set up):

```
alias x='export DISPLAY="127.0.0.1:$(echo $DISPLAY | sed '"'"'s/.*:\(.*\)/\1/'"'"')"'
```

And then type `x` on logon.

(Note this handles the fact that for each new request for X forwarding made to the SSHD on the remote host the number assigned to your X session is incremented, so it *may* be :10.0 or it may be :11.0 etc).

You can put the export command in your `.login`, but that will effect *ALL* logins not just those made from putty.

**EDIT:** The OP has asked why this works. I would assume that you have an alias on your loopback device of the 127.0.1.1 address, and the standard loopback address as the main interface address (an `ifconfig` would confirm that). Most loopback devices will default to a 127.0.0.0/8 netblock and therefore routing will be in place to point that /8 via the lo device:

```
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
```

localhost (as you've already pointed out) resolves via your `/etc/hosts` and points to that 127.0.1.1 address, and therefore that's the IP most services will use. You *may* be able to change it to resolve to 127.0.0.1, but that would probably also involve restarting all your services that utilize the 127.0.1.1 address (`netstat -an` will show these) after you have changed it in your hosts file.

Comment: While this rectifies the issue, it doesn't help me understand why it is happening in the first place.

Comment: @ekaj: I've removed those question marks.

Comment: @dreamlax I've attempted to answer the question (with the information you have), which has involved some guess work.